# Which HTML5 tag should I use for a JS event trigger

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I want to add an element in the footer of my page that the user can click to scroll to the top of the page. So this element would exist without any kind `href` but would have a JS listener attached to it.

Something like this: `<[tag_type]>scroll to top</[tag_type]>`

However, I'm not sure what HTML5 tag would be most suitable for this purpose. And so I wondered:

Is there an agreed upon HTML5 tag that is suitable for use solely as an JS event trigger?

I should say, this question is intended to cover more broad cases other than just scrolling to the top, for example: showing/hiding elements, triggering animations etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still a link, and it can even have a href to the top (even though that's no more required in HTML5):

```
<a href="#">scroll to top</a>
<a href="/more.html">show more</a>
<a>start animation</a><!-- new in HTML5 -->
```

If you don't like an anchor, you can still use other elements. HTML5 does not define any new ones that were suitable here, but you could e.g. use a plain `<span>` or a `<button type="button">`.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks! I didn't know about the new HTML5 use a the a-tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way tot do that is to use `<a href="#">`.  Your thing is basically a link to the top, so  i think this is semantically correct.